# Linux: Search for coincidences in four different files

Tags: bash, search

Scenario: Four files with 300 lines on each one. I want to know which lines are in all four files using bash only (no perl/python/ruby please)

Quick sample

```
$cat bad_domains.urlvoid
a
b
c
d
e

$cat bad_domains.alienvault
f
g
a
c
h

$cat bad_domains.hphosts
i
j
k
a
h

$cat bad_domains.malwaredomain
l
b
m
f
a
j
```

I only want to match the "a" i tried with stuff like this but it's slow as hell:

```
for void in $(cat bad_domains.urlvoid)
do 
    for vault in $(cat bad_domains.alienvault)
    do 
        for hphosts in $(cat bad_domains.hphosts)
        do
            for malwaredomain in $(cat bad_domains.malwaredomain)
            do
                if [ $void == $vault -a $void == $hphosts -a $void == $malwaredomain -a $vault == $hphosts -a $vault == $malwaredomain -a $hphosts == $malwaredomain ]
                then 
                    echo $void
                fi
            done
        done
    done
done
```

Any good tips for optimizing my code? I read something about Dichotomic search that maybe could work.

Comment: `grep -f f1 f2` combined with `grep -f f3 f4` should make it... But I don't find the way to do it. Anubhava's `comm` seems the best tool for this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `comm`:

```
comm -12 <(awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} $0 in a' f1 f2) <(awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} $0 in a' f3 f4)
a
```

Which works using these 3 steps:

1. Get common strings from file1 and file2
2. Get common strings from file3 and file4
3. Get common strings from above 2 steps thus getting intersection of 4 sets

**EDIT:** Pure awk solution:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} $0 in a' <(awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} $0 in a' f1 f2) <(awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} $0 in a' f3 f4)
```

Comment: jesus, what kind of sorcery is this, I have passed from +15 minutes for each search to less than 30 seconds!!! I didn't know that awk was capable of doing this kind of searches, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

If the lines are unique within each file:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 file4 | sort | uniq -c | grep '^ *4 '
```

Comment: What if a line is twice in the same file but not in another?

Comment: Then it won't work. That's why my answer starts with an **if**.

Comment: nop, lines are not unique between files, but thx for the tip :)

Comment: Honestly, I don't like it. Also, the usage of `uniq -c` changes the format of the output.

Comment: It's your privilige not to like it. For me, that comment is useless, as you haven't told us *why*. I think it's a nice toolchain example. And it's easy to fix the formatting.

Comment: Yes, it is a good example, but I guess not the best tool for this case. Anyway, well done!

Answer (score 1):

For bash 4.x (and ksh93)

Create an associative array indexed by the lines of one of the files (master).

For each of the remaining files, create a second array (work) indexed by the file's lines, then iterate over the master
array removing any entry with a key which does not also appear in the work array.

Any keys left in master[] after processing must have been in all files.

```
list=( bad_domains.* )

typeset -A master
while IFS= read -r key ; do master[$key]=1 ; done < "${list[0]}"
unset list[0]

for file in "${list[@]}" ; do
    typeset -A work
    while IFS= read -r key ; do work[$key]=1 ; done < "$file"
    for key in "${!master[@]}" ; do [[ ${work[$key]+set} = set ]] || unset master[$key] ; done
    unset work
done

for key in "${!master[@]}" ; do printf '%s\n' "$key" ; done
```

Comment: Nice solution, i like it because you don't use awk or sed, i will remember it for the future. Anyway, for this particular case, i have used the first solution using awk, which works pretty well.